# My view isn't null and the text is not null, but I get: content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following code:

```
public class MyProfileActivity extends Activity {

    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private TextView mSeekBarValue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_profile);

        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        mSeekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_value);

        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                int value = mSeekBar.getProgress();
                mSeekBarValue.setText(value);
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                        PublicMacros.SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putInt(PublicMacros.USER_SETTINGS_RADIUS, value);
                editor.commit();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and I get the following error when trying to set

```
mSeekBarValue.setText(value);
```

Error:

```
07-06 06:57:57.456: E/(31651): Device driver API match
07-06 06:57:57.456: E/(31651): Device driver API version: 23
07-06 06:57:57.456: E/(31651): User space API version: 23 
07-06 06:57:57.456: E/(31651): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct 30 09:36:10 KST 2013 
07-06 06:58:29.041: E/ViewRootImpl(31651): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-06 06:59:11.576: E/InputEventReceiver(31651): Exception dispatching input event.
07-06 06:59:11.576: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x35c
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1068)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4546)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at com.zoomer.settings.MyProfileActivity$1.onProgressChanged(MyProfileActivity.java:47)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:96)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:684)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:709)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBar.java:799)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.trackTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:655)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:566)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7817)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2131)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2131)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2131)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2131)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2131)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1612)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2494)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2274)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8025)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4675)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4563)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4157)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4183)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4268)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4191)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4325)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4157)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4183)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4191)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4157)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6317)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6255)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6226)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6397)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
07-06 06:59:11.721: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31651):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I see mSeekBarValue is not null. How can it throw missing src error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            int value = mSeekBar.getProgress();
            mSeekBarValue.setText(value); //<-- Error
            //^^When you pass an int value to setText, 
            //android will look for a resource matching that id 
            //but it wont find it because its just an int value 
            //that you're passing not a resource id. 
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                    PublicMacros.SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt(PublicMacros.USER_SETTINGS_RADIUS, value);
            editor.commit();

        }
    });
```

1. You should use `mSeekBarValue.setText(Integer.toString());`
2. You don't need to use `mSeekBar.getProgress()` because the progress value is passed to you in the progress parameter of the `onProgressChanged()` method. Just use, `mSeekBarValue.setText(Integer.toString(progress));`

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
int value = mSeekBar.getProgress();
mSeekBarValue.setText(value);
```

Uses the method `setText(int resid)`, since you are providing a `int` as a parameter. This method expects a resource ID as input. In your code this resource ID does not exist.

In order to use `setText(CharSequence text)` instead you need to convert or otherwise alter your input so that it is a `CharSequence` (`String` implements `CharSequence`).

Example code to get the desired result may be:

```
int value = mSeekBar.getProgress();
mSeekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Comment: This is correct. But `"" + value` is somewhat obscure, I would recommend using `String.valueOf(value)` instead.